# Documents to carry for Europe vacation travel

Tags: europe, schengen, international-travel, switzerland, paperwork

I'll be traveling to Europe from India for 7-8 days… I am planning to visit France/Switzerland/Italy/Austria/Liechtenstein

Paris is the first stop in Europe.

This being my first international visit, I just wanted to understand if just carrying the passport (with Schengen visa) was enough OR should I carry any additional documents as well. For things like SIM card, are there any other docs required ?

Comment: You may find [What documents should you carry with you when travelling internationally?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9651/101) useful...

Comment: Passport, visa and return ticket are the most important things. Info on which number to call to block your debit/credit cards or how to contact your travel insurance if needed might be useful. Taking some copy of the documentation you had to provide to get the visa (proof of insurance, itinerary and booking confirmation, etc.) cannot hurt.

Comment: Are you asking which documents you HAVE to have on you by law, or which documents can be helpful in case of emergency?

Comment: I wanted to know mainly the required documents (those required in case of emergency would be helpful as well)