# Will a trip to North Korea make it difficult to visit other countries in the future?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, north-korea

I'm a European, and I plan on spending 1 or 2 weeks in North Korea, a tourist trip. Will this trip prevent me from visiting any other country in the future (such as the US, as of today's regulations)?

There are several topics on this subject, but with the travel ban that has been issued by the US, I don't know if they are still relevant.

Comment: Unless it has changed recently, you can obviously get both your visa and entry/exit stamps on a separate piece of paper, so that there are no traces of the trip to North Korea in your passport.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Not a matter of choice, but where you apply. Most tourists obtain and collect a group visa in Beijing, which is loose-leaf, but at any NK embassy elsewhere it goes in your passport

Comment: @Coke And if I understand it correctly, it is up to you (at least when booking through the common tour operators) where to get your visa. All tour operators from North Korea seem to offer a visa service, where they will arrange a visa for you. This visa is issued on a separate piece of paper, since the tour operator only has a copy of your passport. *Some* tour operators offer in addition to arrange for a visa pickup at a consulate, where the visa will be pasted into your passport. Booking through one of these operators is currently the only option to go to North Korea anyway.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo All TOs I've come across asks you where you wish to pick up your visa. Not everyone has the possibility of travelling to Beijing (i.e. the actual city, as that's where the paper visa is collected). When I went there, among the first things the TO asked was where I wanted to collect my visa. I chose the embassy in Bern

Comment: See also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/would-visiting-north-korea-as-a-tourist-cause-problems-travelling-anywhere-else

Answer (score 6):

There's no formal restriction preventing you to visit the US, but given the severe tensions between the countries, some US officers may well not like the fact that you visited NK and may well give you a hard time because of it.

Bring as much documentation as you can proving that you're a regular tourist and that you'll return home, so that they have as little as possible to turn against you.

As for other countries, no one but the US is likely to care.

Comment: Source? This answer strikes me as entirely speculative.

Comment: @ajd It is a well-known fact that having stamps from certain Middle Eastern states may subject you to closer scrutiny in the US (though perhaps not in the same way as in Israel). Having an Iranian tourist visa and corresponding stamps once got a White Austrian acquaintance of mine into serious trouble at SFO, which was before the VWP restriction was decided on. NK is considered en enemy state as well at the moment, so it is only reasonable to be more cautious if having been there

Comment: There are important differences, crucially that US officials aren't as scared about people going to North Korea being "radicalized" and committing acts of terrorism in the US. "Bring documentation" is always good advice, but it seems to me that a good answer to this question would include actual sourced information about whether having been to DPRK attracts additional scrutiny.

Comment: @ajd Not terrorists, but spies

Comment: NK is not a certain Middle Easter state. It's very speculative indeed.

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience (and this appears to still be the case as of 2018), North Korea does not stamp your passport. The North Korean visa is a separate piece of paper which is taken off you when you leave the country.

This means that, unless you tell border officials about your fun trip to North Korea, they have no way of knowing that you've ever been there (North Korea Certainly don't share Immigration records with the US)

Source: I did the trip myself in 2014.

Comment: Which embassy did you collect your NK visa at?  The comments on the question imply that the procedure may vary depending on the embassy used.

Comment: The visa was arranged through the tour company. The visa slip was issued to us on arrival.

Comment: Presumably the tour company arranged our visa through the Beijing embassy as they were based in Beijing